# Bootstrap table default sorting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I using bootstrap table and there is a default sorting of first column.
How can I change default column and choose another and using (Ascending/Descending)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 24):

You can use data-sort-name and data-sort-order in your table

For example :

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="date" data-sort-order="desc">
```

The documentation is here http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: "data-sort-name" needs to be used along with "data-field". for example:

`<table data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="date" data-sort-order="desc">
<th data-field="date">Date</th>
`

Comment: Just make sure to add the data-toggle at the table level, not tr or td

Answer (score 1):

(May be it's too late to answer but just trying to help the other.)
Try to add this in your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    defaultSorted={[{
             dataField: 'FIELD_NAME',
             order: 'asc'}]}
```